# Set value on DynaActionForm / DynaValidatorForm in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts-1

I would like to set a value on a DynaForm, which is easy to do in the Action class, but I would like to do so in the JSP itself, by copying a value from the session into the form.

```
<form-bean name="inputCIDs" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
  <form-property name="containerIDFormat" type="java.lang.String"/>
</form-bean>
```

The following Java code works in the JSP, but is there a Struts 1.x or JSTL tag that would do the equivalent action?

```
<%
    DynaActionForm form = (DynaActionForm) request.getAttribute("inputCIDs");
    form.set("containerIDFormat", session.getAttribute("varInSession"));
%>
```

The property will be used and changed by the user using a select box

```
<html:select property="containerIDFormat">
  <html:options collection="containerIDFormats" property="value" labelProperty="description"/>
</html:select>
```

Environment:
Struts 1.2.4
taglibs 1.1.2
JBoss 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? The JSP isn't the appropriate place for this type of work.

```
<html:hidden property="containerIDFormat" value="${varInSession}"/>
```

If you just set the form value it won't survive the submission anyway, because a new request-scoped form will be created. And if it's a session-scoped form there's even less reason to do this work in JSP.

Comment: You are correct.  Here is my ultimate challenge that I'm trying to accomplish.  I would like a select box's value to be pulled from and put into the Session.  However, it seams that if I don't declare the variable in the DynaForm defined for the action, it doesn't work.  This particular variable is used in multiple forms and the page can be loaded from multiple actions.  By putting the code in the JSP, I ensure the value in the form matches the value in the session.  IS there a better way?

Comment: @JustinKSU Well, using a dyna form means no `reset`. It can still be done in the action; if it's something that's all over, could be in a thin base action. Just as easy, perhaps, to use a hidden property. Not sure what you mean about the select box; if a form has a select box, it should have a property for it.

Comment: Is there a way to map a property so that it's value is automatically saved to the session instead of, or in addition to, putting it on the form?  In other words, is there a way to copy the property, without having to put the code in my Action to copy from the form to the Session?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although it would be trivial to create a request processor that checks for a form with a specific property, and if it exists, copy it from a session value.

Comment: Thanks.  I might have to do that.  The solution you proposed submitted the literal value "${lastChosenContainerIDFormat}" instead of what was chosen by the user.  I updated the question to include the drop down.

Comment: @JustinKSU Then your container isn't evaluating EL, or if you're on an antiquated container that can't support servlet spec 2.5, you're not using the EL tag variants.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6492/discussion-between-justinksu-and-dave-newton)

Comment: Given the technologies I'm using, is the real answer "There is no way to do this" with tags?

Comment: @JustinKSU No; you can use whatever value you want in the [html:select tag](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#select)'s "value" attribute, using an rtexpr or the EL tag variants.